# how to convert python hours to regular hours

Tags: python, datetime

Hello the following code will print the time and date the thing with the time is if it is 1:00 pm it will output 13 hours. how can i make it output 1:00 and also add if it is am or pm?

Code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Not a python problem: 'date' from the Linux command line gives a 24 hour military style time and can be encouraged to use AM/PM or show less information using similar formatting strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

will print:

```
2013-06-18 09:47:38 PM
```

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to find all directives.